# How to enable Google search for GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome

It seems that everyone has Google search provider for GNOME Shell by default. But I don't! In `/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers` I only have 3 search providers: `gnome-contacts`, `gnome-documents` and `nautilus` search provider (which is not working, why?).

How can I add Google search? I also like to add Zeitgeist search. That's a thing I miss about Unity

(GNOME 3.6)

Answer (score 1):

Search buttons for Google and Wikipedia were present in the Activities Overview in earlier versions of GNOME Shell, but it wasn't an actual search provider and didn't integrate very well.

You can try a Wikipedia search provider from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/512/wikipedia-search-provider/

I haven't seen a Google search provider yet.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file, called `google.xml` and paste this `google search lense` [code](http://pastebin.com/7315iABn) for gnome-shell into it. (I don't know about the Zeitgeist search, sorry!)

Save the .xml file and put it in: (root access is required!)

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers
```

Now you successfully added the "google search lense" in gnome-shell!

Comment: Does anybody know whether a similar path works per user?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer there didn't work for me. I created google.xml file, pasted the source code from the link, copied it to the /usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers and rebooted.

Answer (score -1):

If someone will search for this question:
GNOME Web has search provider for any website. Unfortunately other browsers don't

Comment: This is not an appropriate answer to the question. Please explain how to add Google search engine or Zeitgeist, or explain that this is not something that can be done.